# Sheetjs problema ao manter as formulas da planilha ao salvar

Tags: javascript, node.js

A biblioteca [sheet.js](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) permite a criação e edição de planilhas do tipo `xlsx` d `Open office`. Atualmente eu tenho uma planilha que contém 3 páginas como mostra a figura abaixo.

A pagina `DADOS` contém informações que serão usadas pelas paginas `Gráfico 1` e `Gráfico 2`.
A pagina `Gráfico 1` contém uma formatação que exibe em forma de gráfico os dados contidos na pagina `DADOS`, além de conter contas matemáticas que trabalham com a pagina `DADOS` ex. `=DADOS.A1/Gráfico1.B2`.

[image: Planilha com 3 páginas]

Para editar uma planilha usando o sheet.js e utilizado o seguinte código.

```
if(typeof require !== 'undefined') XLSX = require('xlsx');
var workbook = XLSX.readFile('test.xlsx');
/* o workbook representa tudo no arquivo XLSX */
// Através da variavel workbook eu consigo ter 
// controle de paginas, linhas, colunas e etc
XLSX.writeFile(workbook, 'out.xlsx');
```

Perceba que no código eu utilizo o comando  `XLSX.writeFile(workbook, 'out.xlsx');` para gerar um novo arquivo `xlsx` que em teoria não deveria ter nada de diferente da planilha `test.xlsx` da qual se origina.

O problema que estou enfrentando é que quando e gerado um novo arquivo o mesmo perde as formulas contidas nas celulas da planilha original, na pagina `Gráfico 1` aonde tinha a formula `=DADOS.A1/Gráfico1.B2` passa a ter somente o resultado da formula, ao clicar sobre a celula para editar não aparece a formula igual na planilha original, e qualquer formatação que a planilha contia e perdida.

Preciso de ajuda para salvar essa planilha e manter as formulas e formatações contidas na original.